# Building an array of objects with a loop

Tags: javascript, loops

Would it be possible to build the following variable with a loop?

```
let mp3list = [
  {
    name: "Minuetto A",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoA.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Minuetto B",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoB.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Minuetto C",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoC.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Minuetto D",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoD.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Minuetto E",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoE.mp3"
  },
  {
    name: "Minuetto F",
    path: "assets/music/minuettoF.mp3"
  } // etc
];
```

It looks so 'patterned' that I guess there should be a way! 
I'm curious to know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course but you will need the alphabet somewhere. Maybe .map() is the cleanest solution

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']; // and so on

let mp3list = alphabet.map( item => {
    return {
      name: `Minuetto ${item}`,
      path: `assets/music/minuetto${item}.mp3`
    };
});
console.log(mp3list);
```

or with ES6 [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']; // and so on
let mp3list = [];

alphabet.forEach( item => {
  mp3list.push(
    {
      name: `Minuetto ${item}`,
      path: `assets/music/minuetto${item}.mp3`
    }
  );
});
console.log(mp3list);
```

or old school [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with  string concatenation

```js
let alphabet = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K']; // and so on
let mp3list = [];
alphabet.forEach(function(item){
  mp3list.push(
    {
      name: "Minuetto " + item,
      path: "assets/music/minuetto"+item+".mp3"
    }
  );
});
console.log(mp3list);
```

Comment: Nice!! Aww I'm new to JS but how amazing it its!! Thank you!!

Comment: @danh thanks for the input! I've updated the answer and now I wait for your upvote :-)

Comment: Guys you talk about upvoting and things like that and to me this is a journey of discovery and I love to realise JS can do things in so many different ways! :) thank you to all!

Comment: :-) plus one.  note that  `param => ({ object })` works in every dialect that supports fat arrow functions.